Vertical wind velocity and renalysis data
What is the difference between NCEP reanalysis1 omega and ERA5 vertical wind velocity parameter? For NCEP reanlysis1 omega variables, I got significantly fewer differences with different pressure levels. Any suggestion is appreciated.
